# Dynamic Intent in Notification Library

Tags: android, android-intent

Have a Android technique question for those seasoned vets out there... I want to create a library that dynamically opens an activity.  Furthermore, I want the project to be able to contain the activity and then pass this to the library.  (This is all based around C2DM)

So, my project 'hotdogs' will have a reference to the library, and will tell it to open the activity 'TodaysToppings' and the library will open up the activity 'TodayToppings'.  My other project 'Weather' will also extend the same library and tell it to open the activity 'TodaysForecast' and the library will open the activity 'TodaysForecast'.

Does that make sense?

Comment: What is your question? "Does it make sense" is not really a programming question.

Comment: My questions was what is the best approach to, "...create a library that dynamically opens an activity. Furthermore, I want the project to be able to contain the activity and then pass this to the library."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is simple. You can pass package name and action if necessary, or if it's main then `Intent.ACTION_MAIN`. So, your library can use `Context` to start new activity based on package name and action to open a specific activity. What about activity, it can be placed inside any other application, no need to pass it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks!  Sounds like Intent.ACTION_MAIN will work great.  From there I can open up the correct activity.  I'll let you know for sure as soon as I get it tested, some android video issues have arisen...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I came across this while trying to save the problem myself. I figured out a simpler way to do this without having to configure any strings or passing in any parameters.

```
String packageName = getPackageName();
Intent notificationIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
```

Now you have the intent you can add on extras, etc.